# Stop checkbox list from click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I had ng-repeat checkboxes on angularJS. I'm using library [checkboxlist](https://vitalets.github.io/checklist-model/) to implement multiple checkboxes with ng-repeat. I had a requirement that the users only can click the maximum number of checkboxes. I used $event.stopPropagation, and it works, but the ng-model is not updated because I have no idea how to access checkboxlist.

**Controller**

```
$scope.mealCBChanged = function($event, mc){
    if(mc.selectedCBId.length > 2){
        $event.preventDefault();
        alert("You can't select more than " + 2);
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="mc in mealC">
 <div ng-repeat="m in mc.meals">
  <input type="checkbox" name="{{ m.id }}" 
         id="{{ m.name }}" 
         checklist-model="mc.selectedCBId" 
         ng-init="mc.selectedCBId = []" 
         ng-click="mealCBChanged($event, mc)" 
         checklist-value="m.name"/>
  <label for="{{ m.name }}"><span class="checkbox primary primary"><span></span></span>{{ m.name }}</label>
 </div>
</div>
```

**Problem**

> When I select the third checkbox, the alert invoked and the third checkbox doesn't click because $event.preventDefault() is working fine. But the mc.selectedCBId has 3 items in the array, it supposedly has two items.

Comment: If you select the fourth checkbox, will mc.selectedCBId  have 3 or 4 items in the array?

Comment: @GaliloGalilo mc.selectedCBId will continuously add the item when you click the checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a pure Angular perspective - not relying on checkboxlist, you could try something like this:

EDIT: I added the nested ngRepeats and moved the scope of the checkCount into each mealC node so that the OP could see how to make nested data work with checkboxes using pure angular instead of relying on third-party libraries. Third party libraries are great at times, but sometimes they add more overhead than necessary for simpler needs.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.mealC = [
    {
      checkCount: 0,
      meals: [{ id: 1, name: "foo" }, { id: 2, name: "bar" }, { id: 3, name: "baz" }]
    }, {
      checkCount: 0,
      meals: [{ id: 11, name: "gravy" }, { id: 12, name: "cake" }, { id: 13, name: "beer" }]
    }
  ];
  
  $scope.clicked = function(state, meal) {
    !!state ? meal.checkCount++ : meal.checkCount--;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="mc in mealC">
    <p>
      There are currently {{mc.checkCount}} selected checkboxes in this section!
      <div ng-repeat="m in mc.meals">
        <input type="checkbox" id="{{ m.id }}" name="{{ m.name }}" ng-model="m.checked" ng-value="m.name" ng-change="clicked(m.checked, mc)" ng-disabled="mc.checkCount >= 2 && !m.checked" />
        <label for="{{ m.name }}"><span class="checkbox primary primary"><span></span></span>{{ m.name }}</label>
      </div>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: The answer is working but the reason i used checklist library is because `m in mc.meals` is my nested ng-repeat, it had parent on top. It will cause the second mc.meals's checkbox do nothing. @Paurian

Comment: Thanks @AbelChun for your response. I've modified the example so it contains nested m in mc.meals. I'm not shunning the checkbox library, but think it is overkill for this specific need.

Answer (score 0):

Bind the input to a variable other than your array, example: another_variable
In your html:
checklist-model="another_variable"

And in your code:

```
if(mc.selectedCBId.length == 2){
    mc.selectedCBId = another_variable;

}

if(mc.selectedCBId.length == 2){
    $event.preventDefault();
    mc.selectedCBId = another_variable;
}
if(mc.selectedCBId.length > 2){
    alert("You can't select more than 2" );
}
```

Comment: When the first checkbox is checked, I click the second checkbox, it doesn't checked and the mc.selectedCBId has 2 items in the array.